# Building application logic with SPARQL Insert statements?

Tags: sparql

I am working with a small team on a project using an RDF triplestore. The application we are building loads RDF data into an `Ontotext Graph-DB` repository, and then uses a set of rules to manipulate the data. For awhile we were using `RDF4J` to interact with the database, but found the performance to be slow, as our workflow involved pulling the relevant data onto a local machine, making manipulations, and then sending it back to the database server.

We quickly discovered that by sending a series of sequential `SPARQL Insert` statements to our database server, we could perform the same tasks in a fraction of the time. Instead of looping through the data in `JVM` land, we are now sending graph patterns and creating new graph patterns. Since all operations now occur by sending "instructions" rather than data, we can avoid the network overhead of passing data back and forth between the local machine and the server.

However, we also noted some downsides to this approach. `SPARQL` is decidedly non-modular, as we are hard-coding our `Insert` statements as `Scala` strings. Thus, we have found that for adding functionality which would be easy in an `OOP` paradigm, we have had to create whole new statements.

I would like to hear from the community whether anybody has ever tried using `SPARQL` as their source of application logic, and what the results were. Is this a tried and true approach, or is it generally outside of the normal use case for `SPARQL`? Is there a way we can use `SPARQL` more like an `Object-Oriented` language besides literally concatenating strings? Are there any other technologies which we may not have heard of which can interact with a triplestore efficiently and modularly?

Comment: Could you provide an example?